# Check if string equals with Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have such structure on the page:

```
<div class="content">Hello world!</div>
```

I attempt to compare using this code:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.className("content")).equals("Hello world!"))
```

But I have false here, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing `driver.findElements()`, which means that it will return an **array of WebElements**.  This array will never equal `"Hello World"`.  You need to either iterate through, checking the inner text, or use the first element by doing `driver.findElement().getText().contains("Hello World");`